# Fetch Data from DB and Show it

Tags: php

I have a simple database `post` and I need to fetch all the title,image and user for that post.

My problem is how do I loop all the data and represent each post on the html? The data is null when I call it on the HTML file.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="post">
    <?php include './php/getMemes.php'; ?>                          
    <h1><?php $title; ?></h1>                
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64, .'<?php $image; ?>'" >
    <div class="postRef" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php //insert comments ?> comments</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php $user; ?></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

getMemes.php

```
<?php
//DATABASE
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT title,image,user FROM websitephp.posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {           
    $title = $row["title"];
    $image = $row["image"];
    $user = $row['user'];
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

**I wanted to avoid to echo all the HTML inside the while loop.**

Comment: This wont work, because of several reasons. First of all, you overwrite all your variables inside the while loop after every new entry. Do it with an array. Also, define the array outside of the while loop, otherwise the scope is only inside the while-loop and the variables are not accessible outside the loop. Or simply put the HTML part in the while loop. You'll need a loop anyways in your HTML, otherwise its not possible.

Comment: but how can I loop the array in the HTML?

Comment: By simply using a loop, for example a `foreach` loop would be a good thing to use here.

Comment: why do you want to avoid echoing it inside the while loop?

Comment: You need a loop  to print all posts! And also you need "echo" funciton in your php code to print values. example <?php echo $title ?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to echo the post's HTML inside of the `while` loop, outside of it's scope the variables aren't set.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>

<!-- Your HTML up to your POSTS -->

<?php
//DATABASE
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT title,image,user FROM websitephp.posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {           
        $title = $row["title"];
        $image = $row["image"];
        $user = $row['user']; 
       ?>
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="post">
            <?php include './php/getMemes.php'; ?>                          
             <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>                
             <img src="data:image/gif;base64, .'<?php echo $image; ?>'" >
             <div class="postRef" >
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php //insert comments ?> comments</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php echo $user; ?></button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <?php
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<!-- your HTML after your POSTS -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note, last line of question: **I wanted to avoid to echo all the HTML inside the while loop.**

Comment: Well it's fine. But the data still giving me null. But it was working before

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result set in an array inside your while loop

```
<?php
//DATABASE
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT title,image,user FROM websitephp.posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $dataarray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {           
        $dataarray[] = $row;

    }
}
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Than using the foreach loop print the results in your HTML

```
<?php include './php/getMemes.php'; 
foreach($dataarray as $data){ ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="post">
     <h1><?php echo $data['title']; ?></h1>                
     <img src="data:image/gif;base64, .'<?php echo $data['image']; ?>'" >
     <div class="postRef" >
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php //insert comments ?> comments</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><?php echo $data['user']; ?></button>
     </div>

 </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: array_push my friend! ( in your while )

Comment: No need for array_push. I already edited his answer, just need to get pair reviewed. `$dataarray[] = $row;` is totally enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use php code in html without echo everything. Just close with php close tag `?>`, insert your html, and echo php code in php block where you want to print. Everything inside while loop with repeat until condition finish.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name where ...";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

<div class="some_class">Title: <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </div>
<?php }
```